# Script works in Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

It's so simple, but I don't know why IE isn't doing my innerHTML changes and other stuff.

```
    function changeele2() {
        document.getElementById("eleme2");
        document.getElementById("workout");
        document.getElementById("workoutweek");

        if(workout.value == "Yes") { 
            eleme2.style.display = "inline-block";
            workoutweek.className += " requiredField";
        }

    }
```

It called if I change the value of a Dropdown:

```
  <select id="workout" onchange="changeele2()">
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
  </select>
```

Neither works a Button with Text

I just can't find it out. Has anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `document.getElementById("eleme2")` you have to save the result of that operation and use that for subsequent access to that element.

```
function changeele2() {
    var eleme2 = document.getElementById("eleme2");
    var workout = document.getElementById("workout");
    var workoutweek = document.getElementById("workoutweek");

    if (workout.value == "Yes") { 
        eleme2.style.display = "inline-block";
        workoutweek.className += " requiredField";
    }
}
```

There are some browsers that make a global variable by the same name as the element id so that may be why it was sometimes working, but you should not rely on that.

Comment: Chrome allows you too much freedom. I knew my code was corrupt in some way. Thanks for the fast response, Sir.

Comment: @HeanzoBeanzo - Actually, I think Chrome is just emulating an old (non-spec) IE behavior which IE has now removed.

Answer (score 1):

This script shouldn't be working at all, chrome is salvaging it by looking up the elements by ID.

You should change it like this:

```
function changeele2()
    {
        var eleme2 = document.getElementById("eleme2");
        var workout = document.getElementById("workout");
        var workoutweek = document.getElementById("workoutweek");

        if(workout.value == "Yes") { 
        eleme2.style.display = "inline-block";
        workoutweek.className += " requiredField";

        }
}
```